# Java long task - Did it stop writing to file?

Tags: java

I am writing a lot of data to a file, and while keeping my eye on the file it eventually stopped growing in size.

Essentially my task is getting information from a database, and printing out ALL values in column A - despite if they are duplicate values or not...

Since there are many rows to the database table, and the database table is across my network, this is taking days to complete.  Thus I'm concerned that since the file isn't growing, that it isn't actually writing to the file anymore.

-- Which is odd, I have no "catch"'s in my code, so if there was a problem writing to file, wouldn't it have thrown an error?!

Should I let the task complete (estimate 2-3 days from today), or is there something else that I don't know going on here making my application not write to the file?!

my algorithm goes something like this

```
Declare file
Create new file
Open file for writing (using bufferedwriter)
get database connection
get resultset from database
for each row in the resultset 
   - write column "A" to file
   - if row# % 100000 then write to screen "completed " + row# + " rows"
when no more rows exist
close file
write to screen - "completed"
```

(using windows 7)

Comment: What file system are you writing to?

Comment: ...I cannot imagine a number of rows that would take *days* to complete on a simple pull and print to file.  At least not in Java connecting to the vast majority of major databases.  Even over a network.  That fact alone suggests to me that something is wrong.

Comment: The network is slow, there are 590 million rows, even transferring the data alone across the network would be slow

Comment: This sounds like a job for the database. Are there some requirements that prohibit you from using SQL to accomplish the job? Consider creating a non-unique index on column A, that would speed up a "SELECT DISTINCT" query, once the index was created, or "CREATE TABLE T2 AS SELECT DISTINCT COLA FROM T1"

Comment: Im using a database!  And this is not a duplicate finding/eliminating task - I am simply trying to output ALL column A values whether they are duplicates or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the stream.flush() method? (which will be called at least via stream.close())

-> so try flush 'regularly' and see if that helps.

WARNING: If you are flushing too frequently you will have performance losts

E.g. try

```
if rowNumber % 100000 then flush
```

Comment: no, I simply use out.write(strColumnA + "/n"), where out is a bufferedWriter

Comment: See my answer, did you mean "\n"?

Answer (score 1):

Its possible you have encountered a section of your db where there are no duplicates, the query has stopped responding (or timed-out) or a number of other conclusions. There is not enough data in your question to really answer.

A couple of suggestions:

1. Divide the task of finding duplicates up (do you have unique row identifiers in the db perhaps). This will allow you to judge how long is left and let you know in byte size chunks when each step is done
2. Add Logging. Lots of logging, report whats going on and when you did it. Log to the screen at least, then you just have to watch for movement on the screen
3. If the data coming out is large write to more than one file. Write chunks to files so you can work with the chunks while your waiting
4. Try and optimize that query to reduce the runtime, or predetermine the results (to a temp table) and then execute on that if possible. It will make it easier to resume if there is a failure.

Comment: We're not actually looking at duplicates, we're looking at all the data, currently logging to screen - appears to be working properly.  #3 good idea, #4 good idea too, but I will work on these ideas if the current process truly fails

Comment: But why wouldn't there be an error if the writing to file started failing??

Comment: @Rockit, like I said I dont know if it failed, or how. Maybe it thinks its waiting for input but the pipe is closed, who knows. My guess is there was an intervening network failure and your app thinks the pipe is still open but there will be no more data coming so its stuck waiting on a signal that will never come. Its just as likely though that you will see it start writing the moment you read this comment because it was just waiting for data to be available.

Answer (score 0):

You included no details about your OS. Depending on the OS, there are ways to determine the open files for a process (On UNIX try: lsof), or vice-versa, the process that is using a file (UNIX: fuser).

I also note that you said "/n" in your example, hopefully you meant "\n". Backslash is the proper escape for newline. If not, that could be an issue since IO layers often don't flush until a newline is seen or a buffer fills. For this reason, consider WriteLine() instead of Write(), or call flush as another suggested.

EDIT: For Windows try Process Explorer: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx